# Rails Mongoid model/view calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, view, mongoid, document-database

I need to do some calculation through a view on a few models.  Example:

```
class Teacher
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :students
end

class Student
  include Mongoid::Document
  belogns_to :teacher

  field gold_stars, type: Integer
  field silver_stars, type: Integer
  field bronze_stars, type: Integer
end
```

Let's say on the Teacher's view I need to aggregate the number of gold_stars, silver_stars and bronze_stars.  What is the cleanest way to aggregate the values in the view?  I'm guessing I would use a after_update callback but I'm not sure if there is a nicer way.

UPDATE

What I want is for the Teacher to display how many gold stars all his students have in total, then silver, then bronze.

Comment: you want to aggregate number of stars for all the students belongs_to a teacher or total stars of students??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution

```
teacher = Teacher.first
gold_stars = Student.where(:teacher_id => teacher.id).sum(:gold_stars)
silver_stars = Student.where(:teacher_id => teacher.id).sum(:silver_stars)
bronze_stars = Student.where(:teacher_id => teacher.id).sum(:bronze_stars)
```

Comment: Elegant I like thanks.  Do you think this belongs in a virtual attribute on Teacher class?